# Is there an equivalent of the unix 'look' command on Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, windows-shell, unix-utils

I'm looking for an equivalent of the unix [`look`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/look/) command, which searches a text file for lines beginning with a given prefix. In particular, it has an option for a binary search within a pre-sorted text file.

Does anything like this exist on Windows? I know about [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html), but it doesn't have the binary search option.

Comment: You don't say why you need the binary search option (or for that matter, why you would use look over grep.  `findstr /B` does what you are asking, but it uses a linear search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `look` in util-linux which is straight from ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux. look.c is simple enough to be adapted to a mingw or msvc build environment without great hassles.

Answer (score 0):

There's always Cygwin.

There's probably a native solution of course.

Comment: In this case cygwin is unavailable - but according to [this page](http://www.cygwin.com/packages/) it looks like `look` isn't available on cygwin either.

Comment: `look`should be in `util-linux` which is straight from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux.

look.c is simple enough to be adapted to a mingw or msvc build environment without great hassles.

Comment: Looks great Luther! If you repost that as an answer, I'll give you the check mark. Also, are there any automated tests for the utils? I couldn't see any in an obvious location in that archive.